# How to get dynamic id attribute for a button which is inside a `while` loop?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Currently I’m developing an e-commerce site. I display product details using a `while` loop. Each product has a button with a dynamic class name and `id`. I want to get the `id` from the button.

Here is my code:

```js
function get_quote() {
  var btn_class = ".get_quote_btn_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>";
  var product_id = $(btn_class).attr("id");
  var user_id = "<?php echo $user_id; ?>";
  var mailSend = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://zti.thecoding.company/get_quote_ajax/",
    data: {
      product_id: product_id,
      user_id: user_id
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(resultData) { //alert("Mail Sended") 
    }
  });
  ///mailSend.error(function() { alert("Something went wrong"); });
}
```

```html
<button class="get_quote_btn_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onclick="get_quote()" style=" font-size: 14px;padding: 13px;" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Get Quote</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to complete the other answers, the code should look like this:

```
function get_quote(product_id) {
  var user_id = "<?php echo $user_id; ?>";
  var mailSend = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://zti.thecoding.company/get_quote_ajax/",
    data: {
      product_id: product_id,
      user_id: user_id
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(resultData) { //alert("Mail Sended") 
    }
  });
  ///mailSend.error(function() { alert("Something went wrong"); });
}
```

And the button:

```
<button class="get_quote_btn" onclick="get_quote(this.id)" style="font-size: 14px;padding: 13px;" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Get Quote</button>
```

Obviously, since `get_quote` is only declared once as a function, `<?php echo $row['id']; ?>` won’t work as it isn’t in the while loop

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
onclick="get_quote(this.id)"
```

And receive in `get_quote()` like this

```
function get_quote(id) {
  alert(id);
  var btn_class = ".get_quote_btn_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>";
  var product_id = $(btn_class).attr("id");
  var user_id = "<?php echo $user_id; ?>";
  var mailSend = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://zti.thecoding.company/get_quote_ajax/",
    data: {
      product_id: product_id,
      user_id: user_id
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(resultData) { //alert("Mail Sended") 
    }
  });
  ///mailSend.error(function() { alert("Something went wrong"); });
}
```

Comment: This will still leave `<?php echo $row['id']; ?>` undefined, without utilizing `id`.

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code :-

```
<button class="get_quote_btn" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onClick="get_quote(this.id)" style=" font-size: 14px;padding: 13px;">Get Quote</button>

function get_quote(id) { //The rest of the code}
```

This will work .

Comment: Thanks Sankha Chowdhury

Comment: Don't use class anymore , play with id , if you need more values like user_id , pass it through the function .